# How to check if mouse position is on the bottom area of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few sections and I want to change mouse cursor if mouse is on the area for example 200px at bottom in this section.

I tried with that code, but it works only for first section. e.pageY isn't reset in next sections.

```
$("section").on('mousemove', function(e){
var sectionHeight = $(this).height();
  var vertical = e.pageY;
  console.log(vertical);
  if(vertical > (sectionHeight - 200)) {      
    $('body').css("cursor","pointer");
  } else{
    $('body').css("cursor","auto");
  }
});
```

Many thanks for help.

Comment: have you read what `pageY` does? http://api.jquery.com/event.pagey/ `Description: The mouse position relative to the top edge of the document.` I see no reason for it to reset

Comment: You would be better of to see if `e.clientY > e.clientHeight - 200`, thats pretty easy. `client[attributes]` are based on your current element, not the page.

Comment: You have `mousemove` event on `section` but you want to get position of cursor below of the `section`.. How will event invoke ?

Comment: @RayonDabre he wants to know if the cursor is in the bottom 200 pixels of the section, so it will invoke.

Comment: @somethinghere, I read it wrong ;(... I would have kept empty absolute positioned div inside section..Having height `200px` and `css{cursor:pointer;} `

Comment: @RayonDabre Why would you add another element in the mix when its perfectly achievable with the elements that are already there?

Comment: CSS solution: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/q7koamck/

Comment: @RayonDabre Although your css solution works, the question was about javascript. I personally wouldn't add another element just for a hover effect. At most I would add an `:before` or `:after`, but not a full on `div`, as this is combining your layout with your content and your interface, while it's much better to keep these worlds separated.

Comment: @somethinghere, It is about developers preference mate! I would do it that way... You would choose some other way! And by the way I did not post it as an answer.. It is just another possibility!

Comment: @RayonDabre But adding styling or event related dom will become a major headache on bigger projects,so best not get too used to adding anything anywhere. Anyhow, i know its preference but its also _good practice_. :)

Comment: @somethinghere, I personally do not want my handler to be invoked every time my pointer moves.. I would keep that over `css` to handle.. I am not a big fan of `mousemove` event either!

Answer (score 3):

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/97/)**.

You need to use `offsetY` that will give you the mouse position related to the section, check the following example :

```
 var vertical = e.offsetY;
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$("section").on('mousemove', function(e){
  var sectionHeight = $(this).height();
  var vertical = e.offsetY;

  console.log(vertical );
  
  if(vertical > (sectionHeight - 50)) {      
    $('body').css("cursor","pointer");
  } else{
    $('body').css("cursor","auto");
  }
});
```

```css
section{
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>AAAA</section>
<section>BBBB</section>
<section>CCCC</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there is this attribute called `offsetY` which tells you where the cursor is in the client's bounding box, so in this case your `<section>`:

```js
$("section").on('mousemove', function(e){
  if(e.offsetY > $(this).height() - 100){      
    $(this).css("background","blue");
  } else{
    $(this).css("background","red");
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section></section>
```

### Correction

It's `offsetY`, not `clientY`.

Comment: What if `section` is absolute positioned and is at bottom of the page ?

Comment: @RayonDabre that makes absolutely no difference as `clientY` is the position of your cursor _within_ the bounding box.

Comment: Add `position: absolute;
  top: 500px;` and test!

Comment: @RayonDabre It's `offsetX`, my bad. But at that point, again, it makes no difference.